# Calling template from controller redirects to dashboard

Tags: plugin-development

How can I call a template with variable from a controller method? I tried following but it redirects to dashboard:

```
public function actionsetDate() {
        return craft()->templates->render('index');
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to include your plugin handle, like:

```
$this->renderTemplate('myPluginHandle/index', array());
```

Comment: It worked but partially, variable is not being passed, this is what I did:

`return $this->renderTemplate('pluginHandle/index',array('name' => 'Adnan'));`

In template I called {{name}}

Comment: You should have access to `{{ name }}` in you template now. That doesn't work?

Comment: I was calling it before `{% set content %}` so guess it did not show between `{% set sidebar %}` and {% endset %}